# Electromagnetic field voltage induction

Tags: rf

I need help regarding voltage induced in load (cables). Say we have a 10 V/m radio field at 250MHz carrier. It induces 1V to an impedance of 50 Ohm (x length). If the cable impedance is increased to 5KOhm then how to calculate the induced voltage (please omit losses, coupling-factor etc). Is the relation logarithmic? Can someone provide me the formula or some thumb rule?

Comment: Unclear question.  Are you asking about an antenna: a closed wire loop, or perhaps a single a bare wire relative to ground?    Cables (coax or wire-pair) are self-shielding and would have near zero induced voltage.

Comment: I mean when current flows inside a load(impedance of cable etc) in the presence of field.

Comment: For coax cables its ok, but there are also  UTP + other control wires which are not screened.